# Django model preimport

Tags: python, django

i' ve 2 model which needs to refer to each other in a way, but of course the second is not read when the first tries to reach it. How could i somehow preimport the models? I also tried from the init, but didn' t really work.

Thanks.

---

example:

```
class Follow(models.model):
    auto_data = models.ForeignKey(Autodata)

class Autodata(models.model):
    follow = models.ForeignKey(Follow)
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of the code, and the exact problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I updated the original question with an example however i solved the problem by reorganizing the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass strings into ForeignKey so they are not evaluated till runtime:

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey('B')

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A')
```